# Inserir dados em tabelas relacionadas

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou fazendo um pequeno mural de recados com a opção de respostas para os comentários.

Consegui fazer boa parte do código, mas como estou longe da programação a mais de 10 anos (meu foco hoje é servidores Linux e infra estrutura de redes) estou tendo dificuldades.

Consigo fazer a postagem do comentário, as consultas, tanto para extrair os comentários quanto para extrair as respostas, porém estou sem ideias para fazer a inclusão das respostas na tabela.

As tabelas relacionadas são as seguintes:

```
create table if not exists tb_comentarios
    (
           id_comentario int not null auto_increment,
           titulo varchar (30) not null,
           nome varchar (50) not null,
           comentario varchar (255) not null,
           data_postagem varchar (20) not null,
           aprovo int (5)not null default 0,
           desaprovo int (5)not null default 0,
           ip_host varchar (50)not null,
           primary key (id_comentario),
           index (nome,data_postagem)
        )engine=innodb;

create table if not exists tb_respostas
    (
           id_resposta int not null auto_increment,
           id_comentario int (5)not null,
           nome varchar (50) not null,
           resposta varchar (255) not null,
           data_postagem varchar (20) not null,
           aprovo int (5)not null default 0,
           desaprovo int (5)not null default 0,
           ip_host varchar (50)not null,
           primary key (id_resposta),
           index (nome,data_postagem),
           foreign key (id_comentario) references tb_comentarios (id_comentario) on delete cascade on update cascade
    )engine=innodb;
```

A estrutura é a seguinte:

```
Comentário

Resposta 01 
.
.
.
Resposta N
```

Até ai, como disse, tudo bem.

Criei um segundo form para ser usado para o envio de respostas, um segundo script para inserção, o que preciso agora é encontrar um meio de quando clicar no link responder, obter o `id_comentario` e envia-lo para o script de inserção de resposta como chave estrangeira para a tabela `tb_respostas`.

Esse é o problema, como conseguir obter o exato `id_comentario` no `onclick` do comentário específico?

Segue parte do código:

```
<div class="window" id="formulario_comentario">
                <a href="#" class="fechar link_mural_comentario">X Fechar</a>
                <p class="formatacao_padrao">
                <div id="status"></div>
                    <form name="formulario_comentario" action="comentario.php" method="post">
                        <fieldset> 
                        <label>titulo:</label> 
                        <br>
                            <input name="titulo" type="text" id="titulo" size="35" />                           
                            <br>
                            <label>nome:</label> 
                            <br>
                        <input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" size="35" />
                         <br>
                            <label>recado:</label> 
                            <br>
                            <textarea name="comentario" id="comentario" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
                         <br>
                         <br> 
                        <div align="center"><input class="botao_enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Limpar"></div>
                   </fieldset>
                </form>
                </p>
            </div>              
                <?php
                //Inclui o arquivo de conexão com o banco de dados.
                include 'conexao.php';

                //Seleciona e exibi os dados da tabela tb_comentarios por ordem de data de postagem. 
                       $stmte01 = $PDO->prepare("select * from tb_comentarios order by id_comentario desc");
                       $executa = $stmte01->execute();
                       if($executa)
                        {
                           while($reg = $stmte01->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
                                { /* Para recuperar um ARRAY utilize PDO::FETCH_ASSOC */
                                     echo "<p class='formatacao_padrao post_it_amarelo'>";
                                            echo "<img src='../img/post-it-taxinha.png' width='40' height='32' alt=''>";
                                            $id_comentario=$reg->id_comentario;                 
                                            echo "<b>".$reg->titulo."</b><br>";                 
                                        echo $reg->comentario ."<br>";
                                        echo "postado por : <b>".$reg->nome."</b> em ";
                                        echo $reg->data_postagem;"<br>";
                                        echo "<br><br>";
                                        echo "<a href='#formulario_resposta' rel    ='modal' class='link_resposta'>Responder</a>";
                                    echo "</p>";
                                    $stmte02 = $PDO->prepare("select * from tb_respostas where id_comentario= $id_comentario order by id_comentario desc");
                                     $executa = $stmte02->execute();
                                     if($executa)
                                        {
                                             while($reg=$stmte02->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) 
                                                 {
                                                            echo "<p class='formatacao_padrao post_it_azul'>";
                                                                echo "<img src='../img/post-it-taxinha.png' width='40' height='32' alt=''>";                                    
                                                            echo $reg->resposta ."<br>";
                                                            echo "postado por : <b>".$reg->nome."</b> em ";
                                                            echo $reg->data_postagem;"<br>";
                                                            echo "<br><br>";
                                                       echo "</p>";

                                                 }
                                        }
                                       else
                                        {
                                           echo 'Erro ao exibir dados';
                                        }
                             }
                         }
                ?>
```

Comment: Hehe...http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Comment: @MagicHat as funções mysql_* estão obsoletas

Comment: @david Dá uma olhada nesse post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted#10680965

Comment: @MarcosXavier eu sei, esse link foi a primeira ideia que me veio a cabeça, pq tem umas funções de db, mas tem myqli tmb...http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Mas no caso pdo é por aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php